# Reading null values in a byte array c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through a byte array (sample below) reading the values to then insert those into a database

I loop through keeping track of the position

```
byte[] data;
position = Conversion.Extract(data, out mydata, position);
position = Conversion.Extract(data, out nextitem, position);
```

The data I have contains some null values, how can I extract these and successfully move onto the next value. At present if I come across a null value I don't know how to detect this and move onto the next item. Can anyone help at all

The Extract code is:

```
byte[] data;
long position=0;
while (position < data.Length)
{
    position = Conversion.Extract(data, out mydata, position);
    position = Conversion.Extract(data, out nextitem, position);
}

public static long Extract(byte[] message, out int variable, long position)
{
    const int length = 4; // the length of an int

    if (message.Length >= position + length)
    {
        variable = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, (int)position);
        return position + length;
    }

    variable = 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Thanks

Simon

```
6F 72 67 61 6E 69 73 61 74 69 6F 6E 49 64 3D 33
26 10 00 00 00 50 65 6F 70 6C 65 50 65 6F 70 6C
65 4C 69 6E 6B 6A 08 00 00 09 00 00 00 0E 00 00
00 53 65 6E 69 6F 72 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 64 0E
00 00 00 4A 75 6E 69 6F 72 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49
64 11 00 00 00 53 65 6E 69 6F 72 50 65 72 73 6F
6E 4D 69 73 49 64 11 00 00 00 4A 75 6E 69 6F 72
50 65 72 73 6F 6E 4D 69 73 49 64 08 00 00 00 4C
69 6E 6B 54 79 70 65 16 00 00 00 50 61 72 65 6E
74 61 6C 52 65 73 70 6F 6E 73 69 62 69 6C 69 74
79 08 00 00 00 50 72 69 6F 72 69 74 79 0B 00 00
00 4C 61 73 74 55 70 64 61 74 65 64 07 00 00 00
44 65 6C 65 74 65 64 01 00 00 00 D7 0A 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 80 C3 29
C6 85 BF CE 08 00 02 00 00 00 3C 0C 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 83 76 C6
85 BF CE 08 00 03 00 00 00 3C 0C 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 0E 76 C6 85
BF CE 08 00 04 00 00 00 67 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 70 CA 4B C6 85 BF
CE 08 00 05 00 00 00 67 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 70 CA 4B C6 85 BF CE
08 00 06 00 00 00 9B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 C0 BE B2 C5 85 BF CE 08
00 06 00 00 00 AD 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 02 10 6D F5 C5 85 BF CE 08 00
06 00 00 00 3F 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 02 80 59 11 C6 85 BF CE 08 00 07
00 00 00 E3 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 01 C0 D0 2C C6 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00
00 00 9B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 01 C0 BE B2 C5 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00 00
00 AD 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 01 10 6D F5 C5 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00 00 00
C9 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 01 20 76 FA C5 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00 00 00 3F
0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 B0 CE 11 C6 85 BF CE 08 00 09 00 00 00 E3 0A
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
90 5B 2C C6 85 BF CE 08 00 0A 00 00 00 C9 09 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 20
76 FA C5 85 BF CE 08 00 0B 00 00 00 F6 08 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 E0 C9
D2 C5 85 BF CE 08 00 0C 00 00 00 F6 08 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 F0 2C C9
C5 85 BF CE 08 00 0E 00 00 00 91 09 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 C0 C7 EF C5
85 BF CE 08 00 0F 00 00 00 91 09 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 90 52 EF C5 85
```

```
SeniorPersonId | JuniorPersonId | SeniorPersonMisId | JuniorPersonMisId | LinkType | ParentalResponsibility | Priority | LastUpdated              Deleted
1              | 2775           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | 1        | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.200 | {null}
2              | 3132           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | {null}   | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.703 | {null}
3              | 3132           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | {null}   | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.700 | {null}
4              | 2919           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | 1        | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.423 | {null}
```

Comment: I brought your edit into this post and deleted the comments; *now* we might stand a chance!

Comment: k; we have your *extract* code... however; how did you *encode* it? since you are using BitConverter.ToInt32, that doesn't leave any room for nulls - it is going to take 4 bytes and map them to an int32. We need to know how this data was stored. Heck, is that just delimited text?

Comment: hi, iam new to c#, so my skills are pretty s**t to say the least. I didnt encode the data that was passed to me from another source. If i find a null i need to be able to move onto the next value, hope that makes sense

Comment: Comment in code says 'there was a problem' - does it mean you have fixed it?

Comment: sorry no, please ignore that comment

Comment: You can't get null out of BitConverter.ToInt32 You could get exception if position is greater than or equal to the length of value minus 3, and is less than or equal to the length of message minus 1. But then you need to be prepared to catch it.

Comment: I can see the schema-def in the data (organisationId=3, PeoplePeopleLinkj, SeniorPersonId etc); however, without a format data specification, I would have to guess at the format... is there **any** documentation on what this data format is? Where did you get this file from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decoded the bytes to ASCII and got

```
"o", "r",  "g", "a", "n", "i", "s", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "I", "d", "=", "3", "&", "\x10", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"P", "e", "o", "p", "l", "e", "P", "e", "o", "p", "l", "e", "L", "i", "n", "k", "j", "\b", "\x00", "\x00", "\t", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x0E", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"S", "e", "n", "i", "o", "r", "P", "e", "r", "s", "o", "n", "I", "d", "\x0E", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"J", "u", "n", "i", "o", "r", "P", "e", "r", "s", "o", "n", "I", "d", "\x11", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"S", "e", "n", "i", "o", "r", "P", "e", "r", "s", "o", "n", "M", "i", "s", "I", "d", "\x11", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"J", "u", "n", "i", "o", "r", "P", "e", "r", "s", "o", "n", "M", "i", "s", "I", "d", "\b", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"L", "i", "n", "k", "T", "y", "p", "e", "\x16", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"P", "a", "r", "e", "n", "t", "a", "l", "R", "e", "s", "p", "o", "n", "s", "i", "b", "i", "l", "i", "t", "y", "\b", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"P", "r", "i", "o", "r", "i", "t", "y", "\v", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"L", "a", "s", "t", "U", "p", "d", "a", "t", "e", "d", "\a", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", 
"D", "e", "l", "e", "t", "e", "d", 
"\x01", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\xD7", "\x0A", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", ...
```

The actual data seems to start after `"D", "e", "l", "e", "t", "e", "d",` and 
SeniorPersonId seems to be a 32 bit integer. I base that on the fact that the following `"\xD7", "\x0A", "\x00", "\x00"` => 0x0AD7 => 2775 and that is the same as the JuniorPersonId in your example above.

```
"\x01", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // SeniorPersonId
"\xD7", "\x0A", "\x00", "\x00", // JuniorPersonId = 2775
"\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // SeniorPersonMisId
"\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // JuniorPersonMisId
"\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // LinkType
"\x00", // ParentalResponsibility
"\x01", // Priority
"\x80", "\xC3", ")", "\xC6", "\x85", "\xBF", "\xCE", "\b", // LastUpdated
"\x00", // Deleted
"\x02", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // SeniorPersonId
"\x3C", "\x0C", "\x00", "\x00", // JuniorPersonId = 3132
"\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // SeniorPersonMisId
"\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // JuniorPersonMisId
"\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", // LinkType
"\x00", // ParentalResponsibility
"\x00", // Priority
"\xF0", "\x83", "v", "\xC6", "\x85", "\xBF", "\xCE", "\b", // LastUpdated
"\x00", // Deleted
```

An educated guess is that if all bytes of the field is 0x00 then it is null.

The fields are obviously of different length. You will have to parse them accordingly.

Here's an example on how you can go about to parse it.

```
public class Person
{
    public int SeniorPersonId {get;set;}
    public int JuniorPersonId {get;set;}
    public int? SeniorPersonMisId {get;set;}
    public int? JuniorPersonMisId {get;set;}
    public int? LinkType {get;set;}
    public byte ParentalResponsibility {get;set;}
    public byte? Priority {get;set;}
    public DateTime LastUpdated {get;set;}
    public byte? Deleted {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var message = new byte[] 
    {
        0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // SeniorPersonId
        0xD7, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, // JuniorPersonId = 2775
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // SeniorPersonMisId
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // JuniorPersonMisId
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // LinkType
        0x01, // ParentalResponsibility
        0x01, // Priority
        0x80, 0xC3, 0x29, 0xC6, 0x85, 0xBF, 0xCE, 0x08, // LastUpdated
        0x00, // Deleted
    };

    var person = new Person();
    int pos = 0;

    person.SeniorPersonId = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, pos);
    person.JuniorPersonId = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, pos + 4);
    person.SeniorPersonMisId = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, pos + 8);
    if (person.SeniorPersonMisId == 0) person.SeniorPersonMisId = null;
    person.ParentalResponsibility = message[pos + 20];
    person.LastUpdated = DateTime.FromBinary( BitConverter.ToInt64(message, pos + 22) );
}
```

Creates a person object with:

```
SeniorPersonId 1
JuniorPersonId 2775
SeniorPersonMisId null  
JuniorPersonMisId null  
LinkType null  
ParentalResponsibility 1
Priority null  
LastUpdated 2012-02-22 14:31:18
Deleted null
```

Now you just have to add the rest of the properties and create a parse method. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your extraction logic seems to be fine but `return -1` would definitely make next call to `Extract` break. This might be the source of the problem. Since you're calling Extract twice before checking if you have gone over the data.Length, you probably have odd number if `Int32` values in your table - first Extract returns -1 and next call to Extract fails.